# Windows Phone WCF EndpointNotFound Exception on device

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone project communicating with a WCF service. All runs fine in the emulator but when I deploy to a device I get an endpoint not found exception with an inner exception of The server returned an error: not found.

This is on a new dev laptop I am setting up. All worked fine on the old laptop.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Is your service running on localhost ?

Answer (score 1):

If you used the localhost for service change it to ip of the web service. When you run on emulator it understands the localhost because it runs on localhost but when you run on phone the phone has separate ip so it dose not understand localhost anymore.